# Show only numbers in PieChartView from (key, value)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, pie-chart

I am using PieChartView to draw following Pie chart in my app. My requirement is to show only %(percentage) not the key name.

[image]

This is my code to draw pie chart in view

```
func drawPieChart(pieChart: PieChartView, data: [String: Double]) -> Void {

    //Setup constraints first

    var dataEntries = [PieChartDataEntry]()

    var total = 0.0
    for (key, val) in data {
        total += val
    }

    for (key, val) in data {
        let percent = (val / total)
        let entry = PieChartDataEntry(value: percent, label: key)
        dataEntries.append(entry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
    chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.bookingPieChart()
    chartDataSet.sliceSpace = 2
    chartDataSet.selectionShift = 5

    let chartData = PieChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .percent
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    chartData.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter))
    pieChart.data = chartData
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think if you don't want to show the key name you need to send an empty string in the label

Change

```
 let entry = PieChartDataEntry(value: percent, label: key)
```

to

```
 let entry = PieChartDataEntry(value: percent, label: "")
```

Comment: @Arti i believe you can use LegendEntry class to show the legends. Not sure

Comment: I did search on google somehow couldn't find a good reference. Can you help me with the reference?

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2569 this is not the correct link but can give you a idea.

Answer (score 1):

Following code solved my issue using "LegendEntry" class.

```
    for (key, val) in data {
        let percent = (val / total)
        let entry = PieChartDataEntry(value: percent, label: "")
        dataEntries.append(entry)

        let legendEntry: LegendEntry = LegendEntry(label: key, form: .circle, formSize: 5.0, formLineWidth: 0, formLineDashPhase: 0, formLineDashLengths: [0], formColor: colorData[key])
        legendEntries.append(legendEntry)            
    }

    pieChart.legend.setCustom(entries: legendEntries)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve legend use on PieChartDataSet

```
set.entryLabelColor = UIColor(hex: 1, a: 0)
```